# Using query builder to return an average in a single query

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

Okay, so I want to return an average transaction size in query builder. This is definitely not my forte so hoping I can find some help on this:

**This is what I have:**

1. I need to get total transactions (i.e. $100)
2. I need to get count of transaction (i.e. 10)

The above would represent an average transaction value of $10

**Now to do this in query builder:**

Step 1: get the total:

```
    $qb = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb ->add('select','SUM(u.amount)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('u.identity = :identity')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('type' , 1)
        ->setParameter('identity' , 1);

    $total = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Step 2, get the total transactions:

```
    $qb = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb ->add('select','COUNT(u.amount)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('u.identity = :identity')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('type' , 1)
        ->setParameter('identity' , 1);

    $transaction_count = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Step 3: To get the average:

$total/$transaction_count

So my question is this, is it possible to do this in a single query?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was simpler than I thought:

```
$qb = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb ->add('select','SUM(u.total)/COUNT(u.amount)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('u.identity = :identity')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('type' , 1)
        ->setParameter('identity' , 1);

    $transaction_count = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```